# How to convert a Date type entity field into a string in Java?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm having an entity class according to the database, which includes a Date type field called `start_date`. There's a search bar within a `jsp` page where the user will be able to search for the data using the name or the date. But the search value which we're passing, into the method should be a String value.

But where as the `start_date` is a type of Date, and I'm unable to use that to search for a data since the search parameter is a string. What could I do to convert Date type into String? These are the sample entity fields I've got.

P.S: This is a Maven Hibernate Spring MVC project with MySQL

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "start_date")
public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This has something to do with your UI components - if you use Spring _MVC_ you should make that clear in your question. Usually the UI framework is responsible for converting HTML inputs into Java objects.

Comment: Thanks missed out the MVC, so I should find a way through the UI component?

Comment: Yes, that was the key point of my comment. I added the tag `spring-mvc`, because some experts may help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<input type="date"/>` and bind it in a controller method with `@RequestParam Date searchDate`. The line format is yyyy-mm-dd so make sure your binder supports, because I'm not sure if it does so out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
pubilc Static getFromattedDate(date,dateFormatter){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Creating this method in your CalendarUtil.java you can call in from your controller.then you can format your inputs and return as string as you want.

Comment: This takes neither the language nor the timezone of the current user into account - and the comment does not match the formatter string - which contains the time information as well...

Comment: in date formatter also can use this, "yyyy-MM-dd". then can remove time infomation.

Comment: You should edit your answer to integrate that response.

Comment: it's done and thank you for guide for improve my answer.

Comment: You're welcome - but the comment still does not reflect your format. And the timezone is still missing. Besides that this is not the best way to convert a user input in Spring MVC - just because it does the conversion for you, if you create a correct binding.